# overflow-y on form not showing on Firefox

Tags: css, forms, firefox, cross-browser, overflow

I added overflow-y to a form element as it has some collapse buttons inside of it. So if the user opens all of them if will expand vertically most surely below the voeport, so I need a scroll.

Strangely this works fine in all browsers except Firefox. Has anybody had this issue? Do you know how to solve it?

HTML:

```
<form class="product-filters-categories js-instant-form-submit" method="get" action="">
 .... ETC
</form>
```

As many requested I will add a fiddle. I do not know how to insert the jquery to make the collapse work... sorry:
http://jsfiddle.net/KE3yu/2/

I hope it helps!

CSS:

```
.product-filters-categories{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 30px 60px 30px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: A demo would be helpful here

Comment: Try setting a maximum height for the container. That way, it won't have scrolbar by default, but will show when items inside expand.

Comment: @Nix The height of the form is 100%. It's container's height is the height of the viewport, which is given by jQuery. So it has a maximum number of pixels. This way the scroll will eventually appear if the content is bigger than this number of pixels. So what is the problem?

Comment: Yes. But if you need a scrollbar, then set a maximum height, that way it will have scrollbar beyond specified height.

Comment: Erm, seems you updated the comment later. Can't say without seeing the contents of the div.

Comment: @Nix I added a fiddle so you can check the content...

Comment: Umm, will need to see the exact thing to inspect. It is already expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-y: scroll;` to show it rather than making it auto.

Comment: Then I would have the scroll constantly visible even if there isnt any scroll. Even so, it does not solve the issue...

Comment: I don't even get a scroll in chrome. Provide a demo of your situation. - @DanielRamirez-Escudero

Comment: I added a fiddle with the code I have. I hope it helps!

Comment: But I still cant see the scroll in Chrome. - @DanielRamirez-Escudero